# maintain the selected options and checkboxes after submit

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have checkboxes and select options inside a form.

```
 <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkedBoxes" value="Reseller"checked />
            <span>Reseller</span>
        </label>


        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkedBoxes" value="SI" checked/>
            <span>SI</span>
        </label> //selects
...
```

Checkboxes are displayed as checked.


This is what my controller looks like:

```
 public IActionResult combinedForm(string[] checkedBoxes, string SelectOption, string SelectOptionComp, string SelectOptionSer, string SelectOptionSoft, string SelectOptionApp)
        { //viewModel=...

          var deneme = viewModel.Where(x =>x.Companies.company_type.Contains(checkedBoxes[0]));
        }
```

How can I keep the state of checkboxes, preferably with the selected select options on view when I clicked the submit button?

Comment: explore ViewData

Comment: @letsdoit I saw binding but couldn't understand how to apply to my project to keep selected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used viewbags for both

```
 @if (((string[])ViewBag.checkedBoxes).Contains("Component provider"))
        {
             <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkedBoxes" value="Component provider" checked  />
            <span>Component provider&nbsp;</span>
        </label>
        }
        else if (!((string[])ViewBag.checkedBoxes).Contains("Component provider"))
        {
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkedBoxes" value="Component provider" />
                <span>Component provider&nbsp;</span>
            </label>
        }
```

---

```
<select style="width:100px" id="SelectOption" name="SelectOption" value="a">
           
            <option>@Html.Label("-",(string)ViewBag.Name,new {@class = "mylabel" })</option>
```